# Fatal error Uncaught PDOException: General error: mode must be an integer

Tags: php, pdo

Estou obtendo este erro quando tento fazer um insert no banco com PDO:

```
> > <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: mode must be an integer in
> C:\Users\Usuário.NB-0307\Documents\Site\Admin
> 2\db\enviarexercicio.php:51 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\Users\Usuário.NB-0307\Documents\Site\Admin 2\db\enviarexercicio.php(51): PDO-&gt;query('INSERT INTO tb_...',
> Array)
> #1 {main}   thrown in <b>C:\Users\Usuário.NB-0307\Documents\Site\Admin 2\db\enviarexercicio.php</b> on line <b>51</b><br />
```

Não consigo achar oque esta causando, estou utilizando esta classe para conexão com banco:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Classe de conexão ao banco de dados usando PDO no padrão Singleton.
 * Modo de Usar:
 * require_once './Database.class.php';
 * $db = Database::conexao();
 * E agora use as funções do PDO (prepare, query, exec) em cima da variável $db.
 */
class Database
{
    # Variável que guarda a conexão PDO.
    protected static $db;
    # Private construct - garante que a classe só possa ser instanciada internamente.
    private function __construct()
    {
        # Informações sobre o banco de dados:
        $db_host = "******";
        $db_nome = "*****";
        $db_usuario = "****";
        $db_senha = "****";
        $db_driver = "***";
        # Informações sobre o sistema:
        $sistema_titulo = "***";
        $sistema_email = "*****";
        try
        {
            # Atribui o objeto PDO à variável $db.
            self::$db = new PDO("$db_driver:host=$db_host; dbname=$db_nome", $db_usuario, $db_senha);
            # Garante que o PDO lance exceções durante erros.
            self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            # Garante que os dados sejam armazenados com codificação UFT-8.
            self::$db->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            # Envia um e-mail para o e-mail oficial do sistema, em caso de erro de conexão.
            mail($sistema_email, "PDOException em $sistema_titulo", $e->getMessage());
            # Então não carrega nada mais da página.
            die("Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    # Método estático - acessível sem instanciação.
    public static function conexao()
    {
        # Garante uma única instância. Se não existe uma conexão, criamos uma nova.
        if (!self::$db)
        {
            new Database();
        }
        # Retorna a conexão.
        return self::$db;
    }   
}
```

E ela funciona normal quando faço select mas quando tento fazer insert da erro

```
<?php
    require_once './Database.class.php';
    $db = Database::conexao();
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');    
    $errors = array(); //To store errors
    $form_data = array(); //Pass back the data to `form.php`

    /* Validate the form on the server side */
    if (empty($_POST['Enunciado'])) {
        $errors['erro'] = 'EnunciadoName cannot be blank';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['Pergunta'])) { 
        $errors['erro'] = 'Pergunta cannot be blank';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['resposta1'])) { 
        $errors['erro'] = 'resposta1 cannot be blank';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['resposta2'])) { 
        $errors['erro'] = 'resposta2 cannot be blank';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['resposta3'])) { 
        $errors['erro'] = 'resposta3 cannot be blank';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['respostacorreta'])) { 
        $errors['erro'] = 'respostacorreta cannot be blank';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['unidade'])) { 
        $errors['erro'] = 'unidade cannot be blank';
    }
    if (!empty($errors)) { //If errors in validation
        $form_data['success'] = false;
        $form_data['erros']  = $errors;
    }
    else { //If not, process the form, and return true on success

        $Enunciado = $_POST['Enunciado'];
        $Pergunta = $_POST['Pergunta'];
        $resposta1 = $_POST['resposta1'];
        $resposta2 = $_POST['resposta2'];
        $resposta3 = $_POST['resposta3'];
        $respostacorreta = $_POST['respostacorreta'];
        $unidade = $_POST['unidade'];

        $resultado = $db->query("INSERT INTO tb_exercicios(enunciado,pergunta,resposta1,resposta2,resposta3,respostacorreta,unidade) VALUES(:ENUNCIADO, :PERGUNTA, :RESPOSTA1, :RESPOSTA2, :RESPOSTA3, :RESPOSTACORRETA, :UNIDADE)",array(
                        ":ENUNCIADO"=>$Enunciado,
                        ":PERGUNTA"=>$Pergunta,
                        ":RESPOSTA1"=>$resposta1,    
                        ":RESPOSTA2"=>$resposta2,    
                        ":RESPOSTA3"=>$resposta3,    
                        ":RESPOSTACORRETA"=>$respostacorreta,    
                        ":UNIDADE"=>$unidade
                    ));
        if($resultado){
            $form_data['success'] = true;
            $form_data['enviado'] = 'Cadastrado';
        }else{
            $form_data['success'] = false;
            $errors['erro'] = 'Erro ao fazer o cadastro no banco';
            $form_data['erros']  = $errors;
        }
    }

    //Return the data back to form.php
    echo json_encode($form_data);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `query()` do PDO não suporta prepared statements. Ao passar placeholders para o insert eles serão entendidos como strings.

Para usar prepared statements o primeiro passo é chamar o método `prepare()` e em seguida `excute()` passando o array com os valores para os repectivos placeholders.

Mude:

```
 $resultado = $db->query("INSERT INTO tb_exercicios(enunciado,pergunta,resposta1,resposta2,resposta3,respostacorreta,unidade) VALUES(:ENUNCIADO, :PERGUNTA, :RESPOSTA1, :RESPOSTA2, :RESPOSTA3, :RESPOSTACORRETA, :UNIDADE)",array(
                        ":ENUNCIADO"=>$Enunciado,
                        ":PERGUNTA"=>$Pergunta,
                        ":RESPOSTA1"=>$resposta1,    
                        ":RESPOSTA2"=>$resposta2,    
                        ":RESPOSTA3"=>$resposta3,    
                        ":RESPOSTACORRETA"=>$respostacorreta,    
                        ":UNIDADE"=>$unidade
                    ));
```

Para:

```
$resultado = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_exercicios(enunciado,pergunta,resposta1,resposta2,resposta3,respostacorreta,unidade) VALUES(:ENUNCIADO, :PERGUNTA, :RESPOSTA1, :RESPOSTA2, :RESPOSTA3, :RESPOSTACORRETA, :UNIDADE)");

$sucesso = $resultado->execute( array(":ENUNCIADO"=>$Enunciado,
       ":PERGUNTA"=>$Pergunta,
       ":RESPOSTA1"=>$resposta1,    
       ":RESPOSTA2"=>$resposta2,    
       ":RESPOSTA3"=>$resposta3,    
       ":RESPOSTACORRETA"=>$respostacorreta,    
       ":UNIDADE"=>$unidade));

if(!$sucesso){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($resultado->errorInfo());
}
```